# how to change sql server product key

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

my version of sql server 2008 Enterprise edition has expired and I have a new key how to change the old key without uninstall or any modification to the installed server or instances.

Comment: Please suggest
SQL 2008 express. Pacon(SAP Application) needs the license key. How do we obtain the license keys?, this is becoming an hot item.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](http://blog.mediawhole.com/2010/06/upgrade-sql-server-edition-or-change.html) article (referenced originally by nopol's answer) it is possible to change the product key of a SQL Server 2008[1] installation by performing the following steps:

1. Open SQL Server Installation Centre
2. From the Maintenance screen choose Edition Upgrade
3. Enter the new new product key

It is also possible to change the product key at the command line using the command

`Setup.exe /q /ACTION=editionupgrade /INSTANCENAME=<%INSTANCE_NAME% /PID=%NEW_PRODUCT_KEY> /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS`

Where:
`%INSTANCE_NAME%` is the SQL Server instance that will have its product ID changed`

`%NEW_PRODUCT_KEY%` represents the new product key that the will be applied to the specified SQL Server Instance.

Notes:

1. The linked article specifically references changing the license key for SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition. This author is unable to determine whether this process allows changing of keys between other editions due to lack of required software to test with.
2. The `/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS` parameter indicates your acceptance of the SQL Server licensing terms. Make sure you understand the license terms that apply to your (or your organization) before using this switch.

Comment: Community Wiki because this answer just extracted information from the link posted in npol's answer, as per @Mark Henderson's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at this post:

http://blog.mediawhole.com/2010/06/upgrade-sql-server-edition-or-change.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.